Featured media created with Secure Custom Fields custom post types is inaccessible by API
I've created a custom post type called "specialist" with Secure Custom Fields (or ACF maybe?) on my WordPress site. I then added a bunch of them and added their pictures to default "featured image" field.
Problem is I can't access the link to said images - wordpress returns error 401 "rest_forbidden"
It only applies to media created with custom post types: I can get featured image of a typical post no problem. So /wp-json/wp/v2/media/107 for example will return 401 code, since it was embedded when creating a specialist, but /wp-json/wp/v2/media/422 will work since it was created with a typical post
I think I've search throughout all settings regarding custom fields but with no success
What do I even do in this case? I really do need those images

I noticed that not all custom type posts generate this issue - new ones fetch featured media just fine as well. So at this point I have found no better solution than to just remove the featured image and then select and set it again over all posts.
